# Send form with associative array via AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that contains fields of an associative array:

```
<label for="my_array[][system]">System</label>
<input id="my_array[][system]" type="text" value="" name="my_array[0][system]">

<label for="my_array[][name]">Name</label>
<input id="my_array[][name]" type="text" value="" name="my_array[0][name]">
```

I'm trying to get this form posted to PHP using Ajax. I've attempted this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: "update_postmeta", 
        post_id: post_id, 
        nonce: nonce,
        my_array: $('input:text[name="my_array*"]')
            .each(function() { values[this.name] = $(this).val() })
        },
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: " + textStatus + '\r\n\r\n' + errorThrown);
    }
})
```

The problem is on this line of code:

```
my_array: $('input:text[name="my_array*"]')
    .each(function() { values[this.name] = $(this).val() })
```

.each() is not a function... I'm not sure how to get `my_array` populated with the form's data in the same structure it would be using a regular form submission (without Ajax).

How do I post a form's data when it is created with an associative array?

Comment: Post it as a JavaScript object

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. `$.fn.each()` is a function, and it should work to populate an array. Are you saying `.each()` isn't working, or that you can't post the array as data via `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @Nostalg.io I think the problem is in my selector - is the asterisk being used correctly to select the associative array form fields? Since the selector is failing the .each() is invalid, I think? :S

Comment: Ok, I just want to first find out if you are getting a JavaScript error about `each()`, or if you just aren't getting any data inside my_array. Even an invalid selector should not return an error here--just an empty result set. But your property also won't assign the array to the my_array property. I can post an answer to solve the latter issue.

Comment: @Nostalg.io What I get now is `TypeError: 'assign' called on an object that does not implement interface Location.` Sorry, last I noted it was an error on .each()....

Comment: The Location interface is used for loading URLs. Your bug is happening somewhere else. See the Location interface: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

Comment: @Nostalg.io When I comment out the `my_array: ...` line the error goes away and the Ajax post succeeds. Of course, $_POST['my_array'] is null. I'm not sure how this line of code has anything to do with loading URLs.

Comment: I read your reference. This is strange. I thought it was just a bad selector for the associative array, but the error doesn't seem related. Still, that one line of code also breaks the script.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've been testing it here on an empty JavaScript console with a known good ajaxurl. That one line does break functionality. The odd part is, the "breaking" part runs fine by itself...

Comment: @Nostalg.io I tried appending `.serialize()` instead of the `.each(...)` and the Ajax post makes it to the server with `$_POST['my_array']` being an empty string when it should be an associative array.

Comment: Ok. I think there is an error in that too, but first I want you to try this. Use the new jQuery `.ajax()` API. The function signature places url as the first parameter: `jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] )`

Comment: @Nostalg.io Did that, still get the Location.assign error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your my_array function() to auto-invoke the function and return an array of key: value objects:

```
{ 
    ...,
    my_array: (function() { 
        var my_array = [];
        $('input:text[name="my_array*"]')
            .each(function() {
                my_obj = {};
                my_obj[this.name] = $(this).val();
                my_array.push(my_obj);
            });
        return my_array;
    })()
}
```

Also, you may need to use the [attributeStartsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector syntax:

`jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )`

For completeness, here is an example with using an object instead of an array to directly control the `key: value` pairs for my_array. Also, I'm using the startsWith syntax.

```
{ 
    ...,
    my_array: (function() { 
        var my_array = {};
        $('input:text[name^="my_array"]')
            .each(function() {
                // Directly sets the key/value data in the POST.
                // You could modify the key names if desired.
                my_array[this.name] = $(this).val();
            });
        return my_array;
    })()
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is working for me. My POST data for this page, with some test variables came out to: `action:update_postmeta
post_id:7
nonce:asdfsdf
my_array[0][]:
my_array[1][q]:
my_array[2][author]:` Of course... There was no data in the input fields, so they are blank.

Comment: @Nostaig.io The Ajax POST succeeds. All of my other form vars are in $_POST, but no my_array is null. No error. I'm going to do some tracing here.

Comment: No. The selector isn't returning any results. I know it's right, but there must be something else happening. Still checking.

Comment: Your edit resolved the problem! Thank you. I see that the form vars are making it to the server now. Not in the same structure they would be if the form was submitted as usual without Ajax, but I can at least get data now! Thanks.

Comment: You could also set `my_array` to be an object instead of an array, and then you could manually set the key: value pairs sent.

Comment: I'll have to figure that out. The array is getting created like `array(3) (
  [0] => array(1) ( [my_array[0] => array(1) ( [system] => (string) ) )  [1] > array(1) ( [my_array[0] => array(1) (  [name] => (string) ) ) )` but system and name should be under the same element, not in separate ones.

Comment: Your answer helped me get this problem resolved, now I am trying to get the output structure the way I need it. I posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929841/change-structure-of-associative-array-posted-by-ajax) maybe you know a quick answer to.