# Change structure of associative array posted by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

My Ajax is posting form fields created using an associative array and everything works, but the structure of the returned data isn't correct.

The form fields:

```
<input id="my_array[][system]" type="text" value="" name="my_array[0][system]">
<textarea id="my_array[][note]" type="text" value="" name="my_array[0][note]"></textarea>

<input id="my_array[][system]" type="text" value="" name="my_array[1][system]">
<textarea id="my_array[][note]" type="text" value="" name="my_array[1][note]"></textarea>

<input id="my_array[][system]" type="text" value="" name="my_array[2][system]">
<textarea id="my_array[][note]" type="text" value="" name="my_array[2][note]"></textarea>
```

The Ajax call:

```
$.ajax(ajaxurl, {
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        action: "update_postmeta",
        post_id: post_id,
        nonce: nonce,
        my_array: (function () {
            var my_array = {};
            $('input:text[name^="my_array"], textarea[name^="my_array"]')
                    .each(function () {
                        my_array[this.name] = $(this).val();
                    });
            return my_array;
        })()
    },
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: " + textStatus + '\r\n\r\n' + errorThrown);
    }
})
```

Results in:

```
array(3) (
  [my_array[0] => array(2) (
    [system] => (string) Some system 1
    [note] => (string) Note 1
  )
  [my_array[1] => array(2) (
    [system] => (string) Some system 2
    [note] => (string) Note 2
  )
  [my_array[2] => array(2) (
    [system] => (string) Some system 3
    [note] => (string) Note 3
  )
)
```

I need it to be:

```
array(3) (
  [0] => array(2) (
    [system] => (string) Some system 1
    [note] => (string) Note 1
  )
  [1] => array(2) (
    [system] => (string) Some system 2
    [note] => (string) Note 2
  )
  [2] => array(2) (
    [system] => (string) Some system 3
    [note] => (string) Note 3
  )
)
```

The solution is within the following code:

```
my_array: (function () {
    var my_array = {};
    $('input:text[name^="my_array"], textarea[name^="my_array"]')
            .each(function () {
                my_array[this.name] = $(this).val();
            });
    return my_array;
})()
```

But my attempts just break it worse. How do I get the desired structure? Basically, I need the second dimension to be index keys instead of 'my_array[1' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure you get the right numeric keys for the right values on the php side, I think you are going to have to extract the names of the inputs via regular expressions and assign manually.

For example, inside the each loop:

```
var parsedName = this.name.match(/^my_array\[(\d+)\]\[(.*)\]$/);
my_array[parsedName[1]] = my_array[parsedName[1]] || {};
my_array[parsedName[1]][parsedName[2]] = $(this).val();
```

Comment: There's a couple of syntax errors in your code example. I'm not quite sure what you intended.

Comment: @rwkiii I have updated my code snippet. The idea is to parse the name attribute into bits.

Comment: Your answer works for me if I change the references of `[0]` to `[1]` and the reference of `[1]` to `[2]`. Hope that makes sense, but yes, this does work to give me the structure I need. Maybe your answer should be edited to reflect what worked? Thanks.

Comment: @rwkiii awesome, forgot that 0 is the whole matched string! Updated!

Answer (score 0):

**yes... Try this**

```
 my_array: (function () {
            var my_array = [];
            $('input:text[name^="my_array"],textarea[name^="my_array"]')
                    .each(function () {
                        my_array.push([this.name] = $(this).val());
                    });
            return my_array;
        })()
```

Comment: I get an `Invalid left hand side for assignment` error on `[this.name]`